# Convert Json Array to single Object in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to convert JSON array to a single object. PFB the details

Array:

```
[{ "item-A": "value-1" }, { "item-B": "value-2" }]
```

Expected Result:

```
{ "item-A": "value-1", "item-B": "value-2" }
```

I have tried following options but result is not what I was expecting

```
let json = { ...array };

json = Object.assign({}, array);

json = array.reduce((json, value, key) => { json[key] = value; return json; }, {});
```

Result:

```
{"0":{"item-A":"value-1"},"1":{"item-B":"value-2"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce like how you did it with more attention like this:

```js
let array = [{ "item-A": "value-1" }, { "item-B": "value-2" }];

let object = array.reduce((prev, curr) => ({ ...prev, ...curr }), {});

console.log(object);
```

Comment: this is printing only second object { 'item-B': 'value-2' }

Comment: no way, i already tested it

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.assign` and spread the array

```js
const arr=[{ "item-A": "value-1" }, { "item-B": "value-2" }];

console.log(Object.assign({},...arr));
```